# 'Return'/Abort mySql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, exception, stored-procedures

I want to abort/quit/return from a stored procedure when a condition is not met.
I'm not sure how to do it. Googling didn't help me much because:

- The version of MySql on our servers is 5.1 (<5.5 and hence no signal sqlstate).
- I don't want to put everything in if..then..else statements (there will be multiple levels of nesting in my case)
- I don't want to call an_invalid_procedure to raise an exception.

Are there alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I do in such cases is to:

1. Create table called `errors` with one column containing textual error messages and UNIQUE index on it. I fill the table with errors I want to support.
2. When I need specific error to raised, I insert the error message into `errors` table. Since it's already there, I am violating a UNIQUE key so error is raised. In my application I can watch for MySQL error #1062 (that's the code for 'Duplicate value for key...' error and use regexp to extract my error message to show it to user/log it/whatever;

Comment: okay. This is also an option. But again, I guess this raises an exception, as well. I can parse the exception raised when I call an_invalid_procedure.

Comment: Other than raising an error there is no way of stopping/aborting a storepd procedure/trigger in MySQL < 5.5

Comment: I see. I'll go with the 'raise and parse_exception' way then. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Something wrong with....

```
...
BEGIN
 <do stuff>
 IF (<your condition>) THEN
  <do more stuff>
 END IF;
END$$
```

Comment: The thing is I am updating some pre-written stored procedure. This <SP> has 10 sequential steps, without any checks! My task is to add checks and quit whenever a check fails. I don't want to have a n level nested if block.

Comment: TJ-: you don't need nested checks. Have a variable `@success` set to true at the beginning of SP. Then use it in conjunction with all your checks, and set it to false whenever check fails.

Comment: oh yes, I didn't think of that. But can I notify the calling code that something wrong has happened that was not expected?

Comment: Only by introducing some output variable.